# Do CountryLink offer compensation for long delays?

Tags: trains, australia, delays, new-south-wales, compensation

In Europe, most train operators offer some sort of compensation refund in the event of large delays. The amount offered and the minimum delay vary between country and operator, but generally a delay of an hour is enough to get something, and two hours to get a decent amount of your ticket price back.

Do [CountryLink](http://www.countrylink.info/) offer something similar for long delays? Only the CountryLink train I was supposed to be getting has broken down and the delay for the replacement bus is set to be 1.5-2 hours...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have never heard of CountryLink offering compensation for delayed trains/buses, and I have certainly never received any compensation for such delays (including one delay of around 6 hours, although that was probably 15 years ago!)

The CountryLink XPT fleet is aging, with some trains being over 30 years old despite only having an expected operating life of 25 years.  Whilst in my experience extensive delays are not common, they certainly do occur.